# how to fix this error "org.apache.commons.cli.MissingArgumentException: Missing argument for option: gs"？

Tags: java, maven

The following error returns when I run `mvn -gs` command in Windows 10

```
[ERROR] Error executing Maven.
org.apache.commons.cli.MissingArgumentException: Missing argument for option: gs
        at org.apache.commons.cli.Parser.processArgs(Parser.java:363)
        at org.apache.commons.cli.Parser.processOption(Parser.java:395)
        at org.apache.commons.cli.Parser.parse(Parser.java:210)
        at org.apache.commons.cli.Parser.parse(Parser.java:88)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.CLIManager.parse(CLIManager.java:162)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.cli(MavenCli.java:407)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:278)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
```

Please help me fix it

Comment: The exception states that it is missing an argument.  You're using `-gs` to specify an alternate path for global settings, so whenever you use this option, you have to specifiy the argument.  Eg. `mvn -gs <alternate path>`.

Comment: Thanks @wjans.Next time i must read command doc.

Comment: The problem is that `-gs` expects an argument which is the global settings.xml file which is not given!